# Как вставить значение во вложенный список на Python?

Tags: python

Необходимо вставить значение во вложенный список. Например:

```
my_list = [['Москва', '1'], ['Берлин', '2'], ['Париж', '3']]
```

А на выходе:

```
my_list = [['1', 'Москва', '1'], ['Берлин', '2'], ['Париж', '3']]
```

Есть ли какое нибудь хорошее решение? Раньше не сталкивался с таким вопросом работы со списком, сейчас очень необходимо решить. Insert здесь не помощник, как я понял.

Comment: Единственное до чего додумался - протись по списку, и в нужном элементе добавить через все тот же insert:
count = 0
for i in my_list:
    if count == 1:
        i.insert(0, '1')
    count += 1

Comment: `my_list[0].insert(0, '1')` ?

Comment: точно, что то я сглупил) бывает же такой затык на банальном... благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй вот так

```
my_list[0].append('1')
```

Comment: Razor_06 , - Мне вот не понятно, как в цикле сделать итерацию for :  for:   чтобы заполнить массив my_list[ ][ ] = My Value. Нигде нету, помогите, пожалуйста, может я не то ищу?